# Character Controller getting stuck on the edges of objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I jump onto the edge of an object, rather than falling down (which is what my player should do), my player just get stuck. I originally thought this was an issue with my `isGrounded` bool but it’s not, as it is **false** while my player is stuck.

[Player stuck photo]
[image]

In the photo I understand that technically the collider is touching the tallest cube object, but even when I reduce/increase the `Skin Width` in the inspector or even adjust the `Min Move Distance`, there is no change and my player won't fall to the second cube/rectangle. I use the in-built Character Controller and I have no colliders.

```
public float groundDistance = 0.2f;
public LayerMask groundMask;
public bool isGrounded;
public Transform groundCheck;

void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
    //isGrounded = controller.isGrounded;
    //isGrounded = Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, 0.25f, Vector3.down, out hit, 1f)
    //isGrounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 2f);

    if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jump * -2f * gravity);
    }

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I also have basic code to make the player fall when not grounded using `velocity.y = -2f` and I have commented out three other variations of the `isGrounded` bool, all which either do not work or make the problem worse by doing abnormal movements. I have tried both Capsule & Cylinder colliders and have adjusted the values of my Raycast/SphereCast many times including changing the origin position of them, the cast distances, etc. I have also used different scripts and have tried to only call `.Move()` once inside `Update` but none of these have helped even slightly.

Comment: maybe try adding a "physic material" and set friction to 0

Comment: Have you configured the slope limit?  Please include your character controller settings.

Comment: Character Controller settings in the inspector are all default values

Answer (score 0):

In the character controller component there is a value named `slope limit`. have you changed that limit so the character can climb higher barriers?

The slope limit value determines the maximum heights your character can climb within the scene.

and here is the unity docs about the [subject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html).

I hope it works for you.

Comment: What would you suggest that I change my `Slope Limit` value to? I've tried setting it to 0, 45 and 90 just to test out if there's any difference, and the issue still persists.